# What are all positive divisors of 7 factorial?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I need to determine all the positive divisors of 7!. I got 360 as the total number of positive divisors for 7!. Can someone confirm, or give the real answer?

Comment: How did you get 360? Showing your method is helpful here.

Comment: copper.hat has said your answer is incorrect. After you try working the problem again, you can check your answer by seeing if the answer you get has exactly $12$ positive integer divisors.

Comment: Do you need to **count** the divisors or **list** them?

Comment: @Dave Only 12? I got 60 (including 1 and 7!).

Comment: It sounds like you are really just looking for http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=positive+divisors+of+7!&dataset= ?!

Comment: @Adam Brown: I wrote "*seeing if the answer you get has exactly 12 positive integer divisors*" The answer Vimzy should get is $60,$ and $60 = 2^2 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^1$ has $(2+1)(1+1)(1+1) = 12$ divisors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

360 is incorrect.

$7! = 2^4 3^2 5^1 7^1$. Now start counting...

**Note**: Count $\{0,1,2,3,4\} \times \{0,1,2\} \times \{0,1\} \times \{0,1\}$.

Comment: There is an easier way than counting by hand.  The [divisor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) is [multiplicative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function).

Comment: @RossMillikan, I think it may be copper meant to use that property of the divisor function...

Comment: @RossMillikan: I was using 'counting' in a liberal sense...

Answer (score 4):

Once you factorize a number as $N=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}p_3^{a_3}...p_n^{a_n}$, $p_i$ prime for every $i$, $a_i>0$ for every $i$ the number of divisors is given by $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)(a_3+1)...(a_n+1)$.

It is easy to see why this formula works from a combinatorial point of view, the divisors of $N$ are also of the form $p_1^{b_1}p_2^{b_2}p_3^{b_3}...p_n^{b_n}$, with $b_i\leq a_i$ for every $i$, but this time some (or all) of the $b_i$ can be $0$, this mean we can pick $a_i+1$ values for $b_i$, from $0$ to $a_i$.

In your case $7!=2^43^25^17^1$ so it has $(4+1)(2+1)(1+1)(1+1)=60$ divisors

Answer (score 0):

Just to generalize what others have said, it's a neat little fact that the number of distinct factors of $n!$ is given by:

$$
\prod_{p \in primes}\left( 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left \lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right \rfloor \right)
$$

Note that the sum is simply a shortcut to calculating the exponent for an individual prime factor that only works with factorials. The product and "1+" part are adequately explained by Alessandro's answer.